# How to get div values that are dynamically generated by a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to alert the name of the item whose place bid button I will click but my code seems to alert only laptop. Can anyone tell me how to get div values that are dynamically generated through a php script. Below is the code for the page.I want to alert name of that item whose place bid I click on. Since the page is dynamically generated which gets item details from a database containing item details.

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*****","bidding") or
 die(mysqli_error($con));
 $select_query = "select * from items";
 $select_query_result = mysqli_query($con, $select_query) or
 die("Query Mistake");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Bid</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="seperate2.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function post_data(){
         var item_name = document.getElementById("item_name").innerHTML;
         alert(item_name);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Bid</h1>
  <div class="row">
   <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query_result)) { ?>
   <div class="col s3" >
    <div id="item_name"><?php echo"$row[item_name]"?></div>
    <div id="starting_price"><?php echo"$row[starting_price]"?</div>
    <div><?php echo"$row[description]"?></div>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-teal" 
                 onclick="post_data()">Place Bid</button>
   </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking... but if you want to identify a DIV that is clicked on, you would usually use the ID for that. If ID can't be changed, then a dataset equivalent. Or have I misunderstood your requirement?

Comment: Yes, i want to identify the DIV that is clicked on, but the DIVs are generated dynamically and whenever I am clicking on any DIV it shows the name of only the first DIV even if I click on some other DIV.

Answer (score 1):

ID of element in HTML must be unique. Use class.
In loop you declare static name of ID, that are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires a counter by which the dynamically created DIVs may be accessed. Your `<div class="row">` block would be:

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $divCounter = 0; 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query_result)) { 
        $divCounter += 1;
        ?>
        <div class="col s3" >
            <div id="item_name<?php echo $divCounter; ?>"><?php echo"$row[item_name]"?></div>
            <div id="starting_price"><?php echo"$row[starting_price]"?</div>
            <div><?php echo"$row[description]"?></div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-teal" 
             onclick="post_data('<?php echo 'item_name'.$divCounter; ?>')">Place Bid</button>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Notice that the call to the Javascript function `post_data()` now provides the DIV id that contains its counter. To complete the job, adjust `post_data()` to include the parameter:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function post_data(divId){
        var item_name = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
        alert(item_name);
    }
    </script>
```

If you prefer, instead of using a counter and concatenating with the static "item_name", you may use the `$row[item_name]` property instead. Whether or not you can do this will depend on whether this property can serve as a valid HTML id attribute value.